# Recognition by comparison with pre-recorded words

Tags: algorithm, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Requirement:

I want a system/algorithm that is similar to the call system in the car that you say a name that you want to call, it will find out that name match your voice. My requirement is that I will use pre-recorded voices instead of Name.

e.g.:
User record target voices for several words in non-English language, e.g.:

- "Keyboard-JP-01.wav" => Keyboard
- "Monitor-JP-01.wav" => Monitor

After some training or even no training, when the user speak a word again, the speech recognizer should able to identify which word it is.

Known tools:

I searched existing speech recognition algorithm, but cannot find one, most of them are recognizing existing languages (kind of speech to text).

It also different from [phonetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) which seems only for English.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) is a traditional and fairly simple algorithm for this kind of speech recognition, though I'm sure there must be better methods nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for this algorithm, I am trying this in my project.