# Speech recognition engine - commands for 'invented' words

Tags: python, speech, words

**Hey guys,**

Is there possibility to use Speech recognition engine/tool where I can define commands for words that theoretically cannot be recognized by any language?

In other words, is there engine/tool which gives possibility to 'add/record' my own invented words which will be given meaning by me?

*For Example i say in my own language 'ukumubamba', which will be recognized by engine and will give it a meaning i define, for example as string 'Uku'?*
(Preferably in connection to python)

**Thank you,
Martin**

Comment: CMU's Sphinx engine had this functionality when I looked into it, around 2009. I know that OS X's speech recognition recognized made up words as long as you spoke them with the intonation that it expected (this was back in 2012). You might want to check with Dragon Naturally Speaking - that might have this functionality

Comment: This sort of thing is possible, but for Stack Overflow, not really something that could be explained in an answer here. If you find a tool you'd like to use, get started and have a more specific Python problem that blocks your progress, it might be on topic to ask about that here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recognition by comparison with pre-recorded words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822614/recognition-by-comparison-with-pre-recorded-words)

Comment: Well I hope I could get little bit more specific answer. I checked some of the engines. The most suitable for me seems Dragonfly. But what I hope for is that some of you guys could tell me if its possible that I feed it with my 'words', give it my own meaning and it will recognize my words. Basicly I cant find anywhere if its possible. I dont even know how to 'name' this problem.